# JSF selectOneRadio function return value as itemValue. For loop to create selectItems

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

I have 2 questions here for the code below.

The first one is, how can I have an itemValue in selectItem for my selectOneRadio as a return value from a function? I know this is working for a normal itemValue, if I put just "0", it shows up on the next page, but any of the getCaseValueByIndex() returns nothing.

My second question is, instead of listing each selectItem one by one, can i dynamically create them? What I was thinking is creating a function called getCasesCount which would return the size of the cases array (in this case, its 6) and then run a for loop like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < casesCount; i++) {
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{CustomBuild.getCaseValueByIndex(i)}" itemLabel="#  {CustomBuild.getCaseKey(i)}"/>
}
```

So then what would happen is that would create the same code I have but dynamically so that If i added or removed items in my LinkedHashMap, the code would reflect those changes rather than crashing for an outofbounds or null pointer error.

index.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <title>Jadestar's PC Solutions</title>
    </head>

    <body>


                <h4>Please choose your components.</h4>
                <h4>To be eligible for the system builder's discount, 
                    you must select at least <span class ='highlight'> 1 </span> component from each category.</h4>
                <br></br>
                #{CustomBuild.initialize()}
                <h3>Computer Case</h3>
                <h:form>
                    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{CustomBuild.chosenCase}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{CustomBuild.getCaseValueByIndex(0)}" itemLabel="#{CustomBuild.getCaseKeyByIndex(0)}"/>    
                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{CustomBuild.getCaseValueByIndex(1)}" itemLabel="#{CustomBuild.getCaseKeyByIndex(1)}"/> 
                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{CustomBuild.getCaseValueByIndex(2)}" itemLabel="#{CustomBuild.getCaseKeyByIndex(2)}"/> 
                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{CustomBuild.getCaseValueByIndex(3)}" itemLabel="#{CustomBuild.getCaseKeyByIndex(3)}"/> 
                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{CustomBuild.getCaseValueByIndex(4)}" itemLabel="#{CustomBuild.getCaseKeyByIndex(4)}"/> 
                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{CustomBuild.getCaseValueByIndex(5)}" itemLabel="#{CustomBuild.getCaseKeyByIndex(5)}"/>  
                    </h:selectOneRadio>

                    <br></br>
                    <h:commandButton id="submit" value="submit" action="responsePage" />
                </h:form>

    </body>
</html>
```

responsePage.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <title>Response</title>
    </head>

    <body>


                <h4><h:outputText escape="false" value="#{CustomBuild.chosenCase}"/></h4>


                <h:form prependId="false">

                    <h:commandButton id="backButton" value="Back" action="index" />

                </h:form>

    </body>
</html>
```

CustomBuild.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Part1;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
@ManagedBean(name = "CustomBuild")
@SessionScoped
public class CustomBuild implements Serializable {

    LinkedHashMap <String, String> cases = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    String chosenCase;

    public String getChosenCase() {
        return chosenCase;
    }

    public void setChosenCase(String chosenCase) {
        this.chosenCase = chosenCase;
    }

    public float getCaseValueByKeyFloat(String key) {
    float caseValueByValue = Float.parseFloat(cases.get(key));
    return caseValueByValue;
}

public String getCaseKeyByIndex(int index) {

    Object newKey = cases.keySet().toArray()[index];
    //String tempKey = getCaseValueByIndex(index);
    //String newKey = getCaseKeyByValue(tempKey);
    return newKey.toString();
}

public String getCaseValueByIndex(int index) {
    String caseValue = (new ArrayList<String>(cases.values())).get(index);
    return caseValue;
}

    public void initialize() {
        cases.put("59.95" ,"Eleo 500 $59.95");
        cases.put("79.95" ,"Eleo 700 $79.95");
        cases.put("99.95" ,"Star Maker $99.95");
        cases.put("104.95" ,"Anzooc 1200 $104.95");
        cases.put("119.95" ,"Eleo 900 $119.95");
        cases.put("139.95" ,"Criticase 1000 $139.95");
    }

    public CustomBuild() {
        System.out.println("Custom Computer");

    }
}
```

Comment: Code has been revised. First problem solved. Next thing to figure out is how to dynamically create radio buttons based on size of linkedhashmap.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object which holds your key and value pairs.

After that you can use a list of these objects in your bean and use the following code in the xhtmls:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{CustomBuild.chosenCase}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{CustomBuild.getCases}" var="case" itemValue="#{case.value}" itemLabel="#{case.key}" /> 
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Note: if you use an object in selectItem's value, you will need a converter, and to set the proper value you will need a proper equals in your bean.

If you want to stick with the hashmap, here a possible solution for you:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{CustomBuild.chosenCase}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{CustomBuild.cases.keySet()}" var="key" itemValue="#{CustomBuild.getValueByKez(key)}" itemLabel="#{key}" /> 
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the information. I realized that part of my code was totally wrong. I had a function that was getting values but I thought it was returning keys and so forth. Also one of my methods didnt even work and was returning null because of this confusion. My hashmap entries were also backwards. What a mess. I fixed it by first getting my hashmap entries put in properly and then using keyset().toArray90[index] to get keys by index and cases,values().get(index) to get values by index and its working that way. So any idea on how to dynamically create these based on the size of the hashmaps?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a possible solution for hashmaps.

Comment: Thankyou again for the information. Hashmaps ended up not being a solution to this problem and I changed it to an ArrayList of Strings and just using string.split to seperate the info from the price. Much cleaner, easier to understand and it works better with my response page, being able to double back to selected information without another handler. I would like the "0" in this line to be dynamic ` <f:selectItem itemValue="#{CustomBuild.getWholeTextByIndex(cases,0)}" itemLabel="#{CustomBuild.getWholeTextByIndex(cases,0)}"/> `

Comment: You can do that, selectOneRadio can handle selectItem and selectItems in the same time.